# не работает except()

Tags: python-3.x

```
import linecache
import sys
  
def PrintException():
    exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
    f = tb.tb_frame
    lineno = tb.tb_lineno
    filename = f.f_code.co_filename
    linecache.checkcache(filename)
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
    print('EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(filename, lineno - 14, line.strip(), exc_obj))
 
 
try:
  compile(&code&)
  pass
except:
    PrintException()
```

на месте &code& тут print uui без скобок. он все другие ошибки перехватывает но не перехватывает ошибку с принтом

я хотел перехватить ошибку с принтом и думал что он перехватывает все ошибки

Comment: синтаксические ошибки не являются перехватываемыми исключениями

Comment: спасибо большое